# Passing eventobejct in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass eventObject with trigger function, means when i manually trigger any event say:

```
 $(".test").bind({ click : Testing });

 $('.test').trigger("click");

 function Testing(e)
 {
 }
```

When the function testing is called by mouseclick , the parameter **e** contains the eventobject, so i want this same thing when we trigger it manually.Can we pass eventobject when we trigger any event manually, Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [gdoron points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10798675/157247) (+1), jQuery will supply the event object for you. But you can create it explicitly if you like, to fill it in with information that jQuery can't fill in for you. You can create an [`Event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and pass it into [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Here's an example of both using the default event object and creating your own: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/uheqen) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uheqen/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".test").click(function(e) {
    display("Received click on target");
    display("typeof e = " + typeof e);
    if (e) {
      display("e.type = " + e.type);
      if (e.type === "click") {
        display("Coords: (" + e.pageX + "," + e.pageY + ")");
      }
    }
  });

  //Create a new jQuery.Event object without the "new" operator.
  var e = $.Event("click");

  // Fill in more info
  e.pageX = 42;
  e.pageY = 27;

  // Trigger an artificial click event
  display("Issuing a click via <code>$('.test').trigger('click')</code>");
  $('.test').trigger("click");

  // Trigger an artificial click event
  display("Issuing a click creating our own event object with more info on it.");
  $('.test').trigger(e);

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? the event is passed automatically with `trigger`

Comment: @gdoron: You may wish to specify information (such as `pageX` and `pageY`).

Comment: You missed the event type to trigger.

Comment: @gdoron: No I didn't. You specify that when you create the event, not when you call `trigger`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything, the `Event` object is there already when **you** trigger an event as well....

> **The event object is always passed as the first parameter to an event handler**
>   ...
>   ...

[`trigger` docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/medXr/)